# Python/Qt/SQLite3 application does not run when installed with Inno Setup

Tags: python, c++, qt, installation, inno-setup

I have a program in Qt. So I created the release with `windeployqt.exe . --quick` It has an SQLite3 database, some modules I compiled in Python, a help folder with a User guide... it looks like this:

[image: Folder view]
Now, if I run `pymepos.exe` directly from here, everything works fine. The DB is clean and the Python modules are called and executed successfully.
If I create an installer with Inno Setup for this files, after installing my own program I noticed I have some old stuff it used to be in the database. Also it doesn't run my Python modules at all. I'm walking blind here since I can't know what's going on (i don't have any log file or anything), if I check my modules separately they seem to work fine, but the main Qt program can't run them.

So at this point I reinstalled Inno Setup (thinking it might have a cache somewhere), moved my release files somewhere else, readded files to the .iss. Compile and nothing, same thing.

Also, I did notice that running the installed `pymepos.exe` as administrator it will use the clean database that it is supposed to use, but still the modules don't seem to work. 
Any Ideas?

Here's my .iss file:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{0BA2A484-5F5E-49F5-94AC-5C7410C70B30}
AppName=PYMEPOS
AppVersion=1.0.5
;AppVerName=PYMEPOS 1.0.5
AppPublisher=Cubix Softworks
DefaultDirName={pf}\Cubix506/PYMEPOS
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=F:\installer_leon
SetupIconFile=D:\Proyectos\QT\PymePOS\project\res\icon.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "F:\release_leon\pymepos.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\D3Dcompiler_47.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\libEGL.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\libGLESV2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\libstdc++-6.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\libwinpthread-1.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\opengl32sw.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\Qt5Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\Qt5Gui.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\Qt5Network.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\Qt5Qml.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\Qt5Quick.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\Qt5Sql.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\Qt5Svg.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\Qt5Widgets.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\Qt5Xml.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "F:\release_leon\db\*"; DestDir: "{app}\db"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\release_leon\help\*"; DestDir: "{app}\help"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\release_leon\iconengines\*"; DestDir: "{app}\iconengines"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\release_leon\imageformats\*"; DestDir: "{app}\imageformats"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\release_leon\modules\*"; DestDir: "{app}\modules"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\release_leon\platforms\*"; DestDir: "{app}\platforms"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\release_leon\qmltooling\*"; DestDir: "{app}\qmltooling"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\release_leon\sqldrivers\*"; DestDir: "{app}\sqldrivers"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "F:\release_leon\translations\*"; DestDir: "{app}\translations"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\PYMEPOS"; Filename: "{app}\pymepos.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\PYMEPOS"; Filename: "{app}\pymepos.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\pymepos.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,PYMEPOS}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty vague question. But to give you some possibilities:

- Your application is not designed to be run from a path with a space in the file name (`Program Files`)
- Your application needs a write access to its installation folder. What it does not have, when run from `Program Files`. The fact that you have less problems, when running the application as an Administrator suggests this is (one of) the problem.

For a test, try to install the application to say `C:\PYMEPOS`.

---

Ntb, Inno Setup does not cache any files. Reinstalling the Inno Setup won't fix anything. I do not think your problem has anything to do with the Inno Setup actually.

---

See also [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333839/850848).